# JAVA search the email ID entered by a user

Tags: java, string, search, arraylist, user-input

I´m new in programming and have to do some homework but I´m stuck.
I need to do this:

As a developer, write a program to search a string entered by a user from the array of strings.

**Background of the problem statement:**
You have an array of email IDs of employees. As a programmer, write a program to search the email ID entered by a user.

I have my ArrayList but now I want to be able to enter an email address in the console & the program should check if the entered e-mail address is in my Array List. Can somebody please help me, I couldn't find anything like that (maybe also I don't know how to search for my answer) I´m happy for any help!

instead of searching for the element in the syntax like I did here,
I want to have the system asking the user for the email ID and search my
ArrayList for it. if the email ID is in the Array List the output should be:
"email ID" + searcElement + "found"  otherwise "email ID" + searcElement + "not found"

```
package searchElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class searchElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<String> emailID = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        emailID.add("simon.hasler@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("leonie.klein@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("lea.hoch@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("max.neumann@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("henrik.fiesler@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("laura.kramm@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("sabine.neuwirth@gmx.com");
        
   
        String searcElement = "simon.hasler@gmx.com";
        
                for(int i=0; i<emailID.size(); i++) {
                    
                    System.out.println(emailID.get(i));
                    
                    if(searcElement==emailID.get(i)) {
                        
                        System.out.println("\n");
                        
                        System.out.println("email ID" + searcElement + "found");
                        
                        break;
                        
                    }
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to get the input from the user , you should read about the `Scanner` class .

Comment: Another thing you may want to explore could be a choice of List vs Set

Comment: You wrote that the assignment says *"You have an array..."*, but you are using an `ArrayList`. Those are not the same; make sure using an `ArrayList` is actually allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you need to ask for the user to enter the string in the console. For that you need to use Scanner:

```
// Using Scanner for Getting Input from User
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.sc);

// Get the input back for a string 
String stringInput = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered string " + stringInput);


// Get the input back if your emailId is an int 
int intInput = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered integer " + intInput);
```

Then, to scan your arrayList and output the result itself (not a boolean wheareas it found it or not) simply loop through your list and use the contains method:

```
for (String element : emailID){
   if (element.contains(stringInput)){
      System.out.println(element);
   }
}
```

If you're new in programming I'd advise you to check for those Scanner and contains stuff so you understand how it works and not just copy paste it without any understanding.

When you'll be a little more comfortable with programming, another method to reach that result would be to use Java Stream Filter with Lambda.

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Scanner is used to get Console input

```
 package searchElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class searchElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<String> emailID = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        emailID.add("simon.hasler@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("leonie.klein@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("lea.hoch@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("max.neumann@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("henrik.fiesler@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("laura.kramm@gmx.com");
        emailID.add("sabine.neuwirth@gmx.com");
        
         // new code
         String searcElement = null;
         System.out.println("Enter the email to search");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         searchElement = sc.NextLine();
           
           if (searchElement == null) {
                System.out.println("You haven't entered an email");
                return;
           }
                 for(int i=0; i<emailID.size(); i++) {
                    
                    System.out.println(emailID.get(i));
                    
                    if(searcElement==emailID.get(i)) {
                        
                        System.out.println("\n");
                        
                        System.out.println("email ID" + searcElement + "found");
                        
                        break;
                        
                    }
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it only is accepting the first email (simon.hasler@gmx.com) in the list. When I enter one of the others I get the message "You haven't entered an email". Do you see the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ArrayList.contains](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-contains-java/) and a Scanner.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter email: ");
String searcElement = input.nextLine(); //Should probably be "searchElement" right?"

if(emailID.contains(searcElement)){
    return "email ID" + searcElement + "found";
}
else{
    return "email ID" + searcElement + "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution too using regex to verify and stream to check if present

```
    String searchElement;
    System.out.println("E-mail: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    searchElement = scanner.nextLine();
    String regex = "^(.+)@(.+)$";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(searchElement);
    if (matcher.matches() && emailID.stream().anyMatch(mail -> mail.equals(searchElement))) {
        System.out.println(searchElement + " = is present");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not a valid or is not present");
    }
```